# Bool = true when it should = false in C++

Tags: c++, boolean

This is probably yet another newbie mistake by me, but I can't seem to find a question that answers it, and I suppose that if my public incompetance helps others in private, that might be for the best. Anyway, self-flagellation over, onto the issue at hand.

In my text adventure's header, I have a struct like this:

```
struct roomStruct
{
    // The room the player is currently in, and its interactive objects.
    string roomName;
    string size;
    bool exits[dirnum];
    bool rustyKeyIn;
    bool goldKeyIn;
        ...
```

And an instance like this:

```
void genRooms(roomStruct *rms)
{
    // Generating the rooms of the house, and what items they contain
    rms[entrance].roomName.assign("the entrance hallway. It's a small room with an exit to the south.");
    rms[entrance].exits[north] = noexit;
    rms[entrance].exits[east] = noexit;
    rms[entrance].exits[south] = livingroom;
    rms[entrance].exits[west] = noexit;
    rms[entrance].rustyKeyIn = false;
    rms[entrance].goldKeyIn = false;
```

Inside int main () I have a functon like this:

```
// Generate the world.
    roomStruct rooms[roomnum];
    genRooms(rooms);
```

And further on, I have what I assume to be the problem area:

```
// Check for items in the current room.
    if( rooms[currentRoom].rustyKeyIn = true )
    {
        cout << "A rusty key." << endl;
    }
    if( rooms[currentRoom].goldKeyIn = true )
    {
        cout << "A gold key." << endl;
    }
        ...
```

Now the issue. There are no compiler issues, but when I run the code, every single item is listed in every room, regardless of whether the bool was set to true or false. No doubt the solution is simple, but it insists on eluding me.

Comment: You're using `=` instead of `==`.  Compilers will usually warn you about this.

Comment: You should use a constructor instead of `genRooms`.

Comment: @Phillip Kinkade Mine didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used assign operator by mistake, it will always set `rustyKeyIn` to true and return true. 
So you should use compare operator which is `operator ==`

```
if( rooms[currentRoom].rustyKeyIn = true )
```

should be

```
if( rooms[currentRoom].rustyKeyIn == true )
//                                ^^^
```

Or just do

```
if (rooms[currentRoom].rustyKeyIn)
```

Comment: Or, even better, `if (rooms[currentRoom].rustyKeyIn) { ... }`.

Comment: I'm a moron. Even I should have noticed that one. Thank you XD

Comment: Don't worry, pretty much everyone's made it at least once. Especially if you're moving between C and other languages that use = as a test instead of assignment (thinking of VHDL here).

Answer (score 2):

You are using `=` instead of `==`.

When you do:

```
if(a = true) {
    ...
}
```

If sets a to true and then asks if the result of the expression (the new value of a) is true, which it now is.

What you want is:

```
if(a == true) {
    ...
}
```

Or the less verbose (and more common):

```
if(a) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `==` for equality and `=` for assignment.